# Database and code structure for a interview page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-design, code-first, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to work out if there is a better way to structure a interview page I am re-writing for a client. I am rewriting the site using MVC 5 and Entity Framework 6.

Currently the database has a table with columns called question1, question2, etc... right up to question 23. When a user completed the interview questions a new row is inserted with their answers for each question or which ever ones they have chosen to answer. This seems wrong to me as the question text is hardcoded into the view so if a question is updated they currently change the text in the view or if it is deleted they remove the question from the view and leave what is in the db!!!

I was hoping to rewrite it so they can manage the questions in the new admin panel so they can add/edit/remove questions in the backend with out editing views or leaving old questions in the db table.

I was thinking of a two table structure as follows (using code-first):

InterviewQuestions
 - Id (int)
 - Question (string)

InterviewAnswers
 - Id (int)
 - UserId (string)
 - QuestionId (int)
 - Answer (string)

ViewModel
 - List of (
 QuestionId
 - Question
 - AnswerId
 - Answer )

But where I am struggling is how to display the interview form. I can iterate though all the questions in the view model and display the question and a textbox for the answer. But when the user fills in the answer and clicks save how am I going to know which answer belongs to which question? I hope this makes sense as I can't seem to come up with a better way of putting it!

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I'd create another viewModel, that helps me relate a question with an answer. This way.

**ViewModel**:

```
public class InterviewViewModel
{
    public List<QuestionViewModel> questionsViewModel {get;set;}
}

public class QuestionViewModel
{
    public int QuestionId{get;set;}
    public string Question{get;set;}
    public string Answer{get;set;}
}
```

**Controller GET**: Here you populate your viewModel list with the question you get from the DB.

```
public Create()
{   
    var viewModel = new InterviewViewModel();
    var questionListFromDB = context.InterviewQuestions.All().ToList();//Get your questions
    foreach(var question from questionListFromDB)
    {
        var questionVm = new QuestionViewModel();
        questionVm.QuestionId = question.Id;
        questionVm.Question = question.Question;
        viewModel.questionsViewModel.Add(questionVm);
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

**View**: in the view you just expose the question and get the answer

```
@foreach(var question in model.questionsViewModel)
{
    //text with the question
    //text for the answer
}
```

**Controller POST**: In the controller Post action you iterate trough the View-model's list and create a new Answer for each question answered:

```
[HttpPost]
public Create(InterviewViewModel model)
{
    foreach(var question in model.questionsViewModel)
    { 
        var answerToCreate = new InterviewAnswers();
        answerToCreate.QuestionId = question.Id;
        answerToCreate.Answer= question.Answer;
        //here you save your answer.
    }
}
```

**P.S:** You also can send the view a list of `QuestionViewModel`, but I prefer send my views just one object with everything else inside. Maybe you need something else later for the view and is easier if its just a object, you just add a new field to that object. Let mew know ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Guillelon I just have one question though. In the controller POST how will I know what the QuestionID is? Surely if it is not POSTed back in a hidden field for example it will be lost?

Comment: Yes actually you have to put it on a hidden field in the view. `@Html.HiddenFor` will be just fine.